# Set a Columndefinition width from code behind

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I need to set the width of a columndefinition within a datatemplate for a listview based on some computation which is done in code behind. So I got this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplateForListview">
        <Border>
        <Grid>                
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" x:Name="gridColumnGraph" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         ...
        </Grid>
       </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

This Datatemplate is Bound to a ListView as the ItemTemplate. How do I get Access to "gridColumnGraph"? I need this access before the listview gets displayed - not when an Item is selected.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Databinding to bind the Columndefinition.Width-Property to one of your Properties in code-behind or your ViewModel.

Make sure your ViewModel inherits from INotifiyPropertyChanged.
Create a method which calls the PropertyChanged-Event:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Create the property:

```
private double _cdWidth;
public double CDWidth
{
    get { return _cdWidth; }
    set { _cdWidth= value; OnPropertyChanged("CDWidth"); }
}
```

Bind to the property:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width={Binding Path=CDWidth}/>
```

Set DataContext to ViewModel:

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

Change CDWidth in codebehind:

```
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel)this.DataContext;
vm.CDWidth = 10;
```

Comment: Well - I dont want to use Databinding here. I have to Iterate through all listview-Items and calculate the grid column width via code. I then want to set this value for that column. I don't know how I could do this via Databinding.

Comment: I just came up with this solution: <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding GraphColumnWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:myView}}}" /> . Is this worse then your solution via datacontext?